# How to scan undiscoverable bluetooth devices with Kali?

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, kali

I set up a Raspberry Pi 3 with Kali Re4son kernel.

My goal is to scan bluetooth speakers that are already paired. But paired devices don't show up when I do bluetooth scanning with Kali's tools and internal bluetooth chip.

Do I need an extra hardware like Ubertooth in order to do that and get the MAC address ?